# Generic Type with any number of properties

Tags: c#, generics

A simple `Pair` class can be implemented thusly:

```
class Pair<TI, TJ>
{
    public TI First { get; }
    public TJ Second { get; }

    public Pair(TI first, TJ second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
}
```

and instantiate it like `Pair<int,string> pair = new Pair(20,"Twenty")`.

Would it be possible to create a similarly structured class that takes an unknown number of types in it's constructor and then creates properties to match. Something like `Group<int,string,double> = new Group(20,"Twenty",20.0)` would be valid but so would `Group<int,string,string,double,int> = new Group(20,"Tw","en",20.0,20)`.

Ideally the new properties would be accessible through `.First`, `.Second`, `.Third` etc.

I have no idea if this is possible, I have no need for it either, this is a purely theoretical question.

Comment: With T4, you can write something that would generate the code to manage this case.

Comment: Agreed, didn't see that in my search for some reason.

Comment: Look at the [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: If you are thinking about writing such a class, as @DStanley mentioned there is an existing .NET structure called `Tuple` which takes N generic types in this format.

Comment: Take a look at how [Action<> or Func<>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,87d60abb7092d5a4) are implemented

Comment: Tbf, `Tuple` appears to do exactly this, thanks @GEEF

Comment: Note that each "flavor" of `Tuple` is a distinct class.  If you're asking if _one_ class can do that, the answer is no.

Comment: @DStanley, that's an important distinction that I wasn't aware of, thank you